# Is it possible to return something to a function from appended HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

### Is it possible to return something to a function from appended HTML?

In my case, something that determines what button was pressed in that HTML.

---

**Scenario**

I am making a file menu system for web storage. You have other storage, *bitmapr* web storage, and then local disk. I want to be able to create a file selection system using `jQuery`. (e.g: I click select on *bitmapr* web storage, and then the function that called that returns that I clicked *bitmapr* web storage. (or an rational value that means that.)

**Problem**

I'm not sure how to tackle this scenario. I've tried using `onclick` returns, that doesn't work, and jquery append doesn't return what happens on `onclick`.
Is there a way to solve the scenario posted above?

**Program code**

*Modal display function*

```
var advancedModal = function(html, title, msg, color) {
  $("body").append(`
      <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-opacity w3-display-middle modal">
        <header class="w3-container w3-${color}">
          <span onclick="$(this).parent().parent().remove()" class="w3-button w3-display-topright">&times;</span>
          <h2>${title}</h2>
          <small>${msg}</small>
        </header>
        ${html}
        <footer class="w3-container w3-${color}">
          <p>bitmapr</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>`);
    return (something determining what button was pressed)
};
```

*advancedModal call*

```
advancedModal(`

      <div class="w3-container w3-animate-opacity">
          <ul class="w3-ul">
            <li class="w3-light-grey w3-animate-opacity" onclick="$('ul', this).toggle();">
                <i class="fa fa-question">&nbsp;</i><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> &nbsp;Web Storage
                <button class="w3-button w3-red" onclick="resetStorage()">Delete All</button>
                <ul class="w3-ul">
                  ${otherStorageHTML}
                </ul>
            </li>

            <li class="w3-blue blueGradient w3-animate-opacity" onclick="$('ul', this).toggle();">
                <i class="fa fa-images">&nbsp;</i><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> &nbsp;<b>bitmapr</b> Web Storage
                <button class="w3-button w3-teal" onclick="return 'clicked me'">Select</button>

                <ul class="w3-ul">
                  ${bitmaprHTML}
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="w3-blue w3-deep-purple w3-animate-opacity" onclick="$('ul', this).toggle();">
                <i class="fa fa-archive">&nbsp;</i><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i> &nbsp;Local Disk Storage
                <button class="w3-button w3-teal" onclick="">Select</button>

                <ul class="w3-ul">
                  Not Available Now
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      `, "Open", spaceLeft + "MB remaining in virtual storage", "blue"));
```

*Notice: All of the `${}` variables are defined correctly.*

**Text diagram**

```
var value = advancedModal(...)

advancedModal(html, title, etc...) {
  prints out html, but on click of a button, return a value corresponding to the button
}
```

**Visual diagram**

[image: The diagram]

**Extra thing**

Before flagging/closing, please post in comments what your questions are or what you want cleared up. I tried hard to explain it all here but there may be something I am missing. Thanks.

Comment: remember that the button is clicked way after the append method has done it's job. SO the `advanceModal` function cannot return the information you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of returning a value, you can pass a callback. This can be a new parameter.

```
var advancedModal = function(html, title, msg, color,callback) {};
```

Now you can use a **delegated** method to call on when a button is clicked.

```
var advancedModal = function(html, title, msg, color,callback) {
    ... appending ...
    $('.w3-container').on("click","button",callback);
};
```

This will call the callback function on any button that is clicked. Here is an example:

```
advancedModal(html, title, msg, color,function(){
    console.log(this); // <-- this is the button
});
```

It will be a good idea to give the button tag an attribute that allows you to identify it.

**Working Example:** [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zanhvotq/8/)